# error when inserting data to a partitioned table in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-partitions

I am seeing an error when I try to insert data into a partitioned table in hive, here is the details:

The table:

```
CREATE　TABLE partitionedemp(emp_no int, birth_date string, first_name string, last_name string) Partitioned By(gender string, hire_date string) stored as sequencefile;
```

The data looks like below:
[image]

The insert script:

```
insert into table partitionedemp partition(gender, hire_date) select emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date from emp;
```

Here is the error I received:

*FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10096]: Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict*

I followed some online suggestions by executing the following two lines first:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

And here is the new error message I received:
[image]

AT the end it says:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 14.39 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 14 seconds 390 msec
```

Updated: I followed the suggestion below by @leftjoin, and here is the new update, still not working. Any missing or wrong scripting?

[image]

Comment: Recreate table with one partition field. It seems like there are two partitioned fields and you inserting only in partition(hire_date)

Answer (score 1):

Follow suggestions in the exception message and increase these values:

For example

```
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000;  
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;
```

And I suggest you to reduce the number of partitions if possible. Remove gender, it will reduce the number of partitions. Too many small files is not good idea for hadoop

Comment: Thank you, I updated my original post in order to insert a screenshot, please review the question again and comment again, thank you very much.

Comment: I added more memory to the vm where the hadoop is running on, hoping to resolve the issue if it is caused by resource shortage and I also followed the suggestion to use only one partition, removed gender, here is the new insert:
`insert into table parted1emp partition(hire_date) select emp_no, gender, birth_date, first_name, last_name, hire_date from emp;`

still reporting memory shortage but seems not true, I described this new issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174184/why-hive-failed-for-insufficient-virtual-memory)

Comment: Read this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/hive-memory-settings-resolve-out-of-memory-errors-using-azure-hdinsight/  and this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shanyu/2014/07/31/hadoop-yarn-memory-settings-in-hdinsight/  about OOM exeptions.